# a basic calculus problem with a series and a integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

it is always true that ?

$$ \int _{a}^{b} f(x)dx > \sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n) $$

where a and b are integers. Providing the funcion is always increasing/decreasing  $ f'(x) >0 $ or $f'(x)<0)$ on the nterval $ (a,b) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

if we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{k=a}^b \;  f(k) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

It is just a few pictures,

Answer (score 2):

Is not always true.
Take $f(x) = x$, and $a = 0, b = 1$.

Then $\int_{0}^{1}x dx = \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \Bigg|_{0}^{1} = \dfrac{1}{2} < 1 = 1 + 0 = \sum_{n=0}^{1} n$